# Heat-sensitive touch compatibility issues

Tags: android, compatibility, touchscreen

After releasing my product, I've started getting complaints that a certain screen was not working for some phones.  After a lot of research and a lot of attempts to fix this issue, I found out that phones that are controlled by heat instead of pressure have this issue.  Unfortunately I have only identified the problem.  What is happening is the mouse up and mouse move motion events seem to be the same motion. Here is how my code works:

```
if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
{
    lockdown=true;
}
else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && lockdown==false)
{
     ...
}
else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
{
    ...
    lockdown=false;
}
```

This code works on a pressure touch phone like mine just fine.  It's designed that while the touch is dragged certain things will not function.  I could really use some insight on how to fix this issue.

Comment: this is the first time i've read about heat-enabled touch screen. any example of a device that has this technology?

Comment: Droid X is the most common that i have run into.  I also had someone with a tablet saying they had the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried contacting or researching on motorola developers site?

Comment: Its not just motorolo phones there are some others like htc g2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after an exhuasting night of going back and forth with my testers this is what ive come up with

```
// somewhere in the prior code a pressure sample is needed
public float dwnPressure
if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
{
 dwnPressure=float(event.getPressure()*0.99)
}
```

back to the code where i had problems

```
if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
{
 if(event.getPressure>dwnPressure)
 {
  lockdown=true;
 }
}
else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && lockdown==false)
{
 ...
}
else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
{
...
 lockdown=false;
}
```

this change works perfectly on some of the phones that had the problem prior.  Some phones there is a significant performance improvement but is a bit finicky.  I figured id at least share my hard work even if it isn't 100%, since this question wasn't answered as fast as im used to on stackoverflow

Comment: i applied the lockdown preasure you mention, however I used a switch for the event instead of all the ifs :S